# Make name variable using another variable?

Tags: c++, variables

Lets say we have 3 variables called:
var1, var2, var3

What I want do is make name variable using another variable example:

```
for (i=1;i<3;i++)
  cout<<var + (there should be added variable i , ex.1)
```

after combination there should be "var1"  and var1 will be printed.

I know that you will suggest to use vector but I would like to ask if this is possible to be made without using vector on c++.

Comment: Presumably you don't want to use other collections like `std::map` or even a simple array either?

Comment: @Bathsheba  Thnx for reply. I'm not sure how to use collections like std::map .  I was looking if it's allowed to make variable name or generate variable name inside source code

Comment: Sadly not. By the way, if you re-word your question (remove wana etc.) then folk may well retract their downvotes.

Comment: @rinor4ever You cannot have s.th. like _'variable names'_ with a `std::map`. What you can have is a `std::map<std::string,X>` to refer `X` type values using a `std::string` key.

Comment: @Bathsheba Thanks for suggestion. I haven't thinked about those words but you're right, I will try to write on the best way. Sorry for my English, English is not my first language.

Comment: @rinor4ever: pleasure. 2 upvotes already ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this in C++. Conceptually, compilation removes all explicit variable names.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in C++, but you can use an array instead (assuming `var1`, `var2` and `var3` have type `int`):

```
std::array<int, 3> arr { 43, 12, 32 };
for (int i : arr)
    std::cout << (var + i);
```

or (prior to C++11):

```
int arr[3] = { 43, 12, 32 };
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    std::cout << (var + arr[i]);
```